# Regex command line argument changing value between node and npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line, glob

Working with node.js, I stumbled upon a behavior I cannot explain regarding command line arguments :

I've got a program which takes a regex to detect test files. This regex is passed via a command line argument :

```bash
node index.js --require src/**/*.js
```

When I do that, I obtain what I imagined. Let's say for the example I got the following files detected in my src folder (I log with a simple **console.log(process.argv)**) :

```
a.js
b.js
shared/c.js
shared/d.js
```

Now if I configure a npm script which launch the same command :

```
"test": "node index.js --require src/**/*.js
```

and launch it :

```bash
npm test
```

The result is :

```
a.js
b.js
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening  ? Thanks

I created a [mini repo](https://github.com/Orodan/regex-command-line-demo) to reproduce for those interested (I run node 16.19.0)

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex, that's a filename wildcard (aka glob). `**` is a `bash` extension for recursive matching. The npm script is using `sh`, which doesn't have that wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm uses `/bin/sh` by default to execute your scripts. Unlike bash or zsh (which you are probably using on the command line), `sh` does not understand `**`.

You can change the shell used by npm with:

```
npm config set script-shell bash
```

Comment: Lost way too much time on that, thanks ! So if I want to make sure my script works no matter the computer, operating system or npm config, I got to look for my files inside my program by passing my argument as a simple string like 'node index.js --require 'src/**/*.js' right ?

Comment: Yes, the most portable way would be to perform wildcard expansion in JavaScript, perhaps using https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob. Barmar's solution should also work

Answer (score 2):

you need to execute the command using `bash` to make use of its filename wildcard extensions.

```
"test": "bash -c 'node index.js --require src/**/*.js'"
```

Comment: I'm not used to working on windows but by default windows users do not have access to bash right ? They're using powershell I think

Comment: I'm not familiar with powershell. I assumed you were on Linux.

Comment: I am, just looking for a solution anyone - no matter the operating system - could use :)